# Plural of "abacus"

Tags: meaning, etymology, grammar, latin, roots

A colleague and I were having a discussion as to the proper plural form of *abacus*. I believe the plural would be *abacuses* and he feels that the proper form would be *abaci*. I believe that *abacuses* is more appropriate as it derives from the root word and *abaci* is a forked word that is part of the Arabic language.

Any opinions or history to this matter would be appreciated.

Comment: While the word *abacus* does indeed originate in the Semitic languages (which include Arabic), it comes to us through Latin. From the Oxford dictionaries on-line: *Origin: late Middle English (denoting a board strewn with sand on which to draw figures): from Latin, from Greek abax, abak- 'slab, drawing board', of Semitic origin; probably related to Hebrew 'āḇāq 'dust'*

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As RGW1976 said, both *abacuses* and *abaci* are correct. Arabic has nothing to do with the matter: the English word *abacus* is a direct borrowing of Latin *abacus*, so it comes with the Latin plural *abaci*. It also forms the native English plural *abacuses*. Other examples of this two-plurals phenomenon are the plurals *appendixes* and *appendices*, *formulas* and *formulae*, and *indexes* and *indices*.

In case you’re curious, the Latin word is itself a borrowing of *abakos*, the genitive of Greek *abax* 'counting board'. This in turn is probably a borrowing of Hebrew *’ābāq* 'dust', so the word may in fact have Arabic relatives, but they have absolutely no bearing on how it forms its plural in English.

Comment: Excellent, I didn't know it was based on the Greek genitive. Ernout compares it to *delphinus, elephantus,* and *trigonus*.

Comment: I'd guess it's more likely a borrowing from Phoenician than Hebrew, since the Phoenicians were the traders.

Answer (score 4):

According to Merriam-Webster, "abacus" has two proper plural forms: [abaci and abacuses.](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/abacus)

Looks like you were both correct!

Personally, I would tend to use your choice of "abacuses" over "abaci" as I think the latter could be confusing to some.